React-native deeplink won't return to app
i'm looking for advice on how to implement deeplink in a react-native app. I have 3 screens - PaymentScreen.jsx, HomeScreen.jsx and OBPaymentResults.jsx. I also have Navigator.jsx.
I'm having a hard time making deeplink work and need your guidance. The process i intend to have is this:

User pushes a button on the PaymentScreen, which opens web browser with website X. The website recieves the request with callback parameter (my deeplink, like mypay://ob_payment_results/12)
User provides some input in the browser window
the website X upon finishing its job, shall call the deeplink to return the focus to the app.

The problem i'm faced is that:

The web site X won't close the webbroser and shift focus back to the app. Meaning calling the deeplink didn't work out.
Within the HomeScreen.jsx i also tried to call the deeplink using a button. It won't open the correct screen OBPaymentResults.jsx, instead staying on the  HomeScreen.jsx
When i used adb it just open the HomeScreen.jsx.

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following structure:
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="mypay" android:host="ob_payment_results"/>

      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="mypay" android:host="home"/>

      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="whimsysketchbook.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>

      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

My TabNavigator.jsx has the following structure:
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
/* eslint-disable no-alert */
/* eslint-disable react/no-unstable-nested-components */
// TabNavigator.js
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  LogBox
} from "react-native";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { ScannerScreen } from "./ScannerScreen";
import { openExternalLink } from "./utils";
import DetailScreen from "./DetailScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";
import PayScreenSummary from "./PayScreenSummary";
import PaymentScreenPaymentSource from "./PaymentScreenPaymentSource";



import OBPaymentResults from "./OBPaymentResults";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";


/**
 * Linking Configuration
 */
const linking = {
  // Prefixes accepted by the navigation container, should match the added schemes
  prefixes: ["mypay://"],
  // Route config to map uri paths to screens
  config: {
    // Initial route name to be added to the stack before any further navigation,
    // should match one of the available screens
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    screens: {
      // myapp://home -> HomeScreen
      OBPaymentResults: {
        path: 'ob_payment_results/:consent_id',
        parse: {
          consent_id: Number,
        },
      },
      // myapp://details/1 -> DetailsScreen with param id: 1
      Home: {
        path: 'home'
      },
    },
  },

  async getInitialURL() {
    // Check if app was opened from a deep link
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    if (url != null) {
      return url;
    }

    // Check if there is an initial firebase notification
    const message = await messaging().getInitialNotification();

    // Get the `url` property from the notification which corresponds to a screen
    // This property needs to be set on the notification payload when sending it
    return message?.data?.url;
  }
};

/**
 * Stack Navigator
 */
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Scanner"
        component={ScannerScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: "Scanner",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="PayScreenSummary" component={PayScreenSummary} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PaymentScreenPaymentSource"
        component={PaymentScreenPaymentSource}
      />

      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OBPaymentResults"
        component={OBPaymentResults}
        options={({ route }) => ({ consent_id: route.params.consent_id })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavigator;


I also have HomeScreen, which keeps opening whenever i call the deeplink, instead of OBPaymentResults.
My target screen OBPaymentResults is super minimalistic:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Linking,
} from "react-native";


const OBPaymentResults = ({route, navigation}) => {
  console.log(route);
  console.log(route.params.consent_id);




  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />

      <TextInput
        value=''
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default OBPaymentResults;


I have used the Android Debug Bridge with the activity manager (am) tool to test that the intent filter URIs I specified for deep linking resolves to the correct app activity.

➜  ~ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "mypay://ob_payment_results/12" com.mypay

AND
➜  ~ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "mypay://ob_payment_results/12"

Give proper output:
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mypay://ob_payment_results/... pkg=com.mypay }
Status: ok
LaunchState: COLD
Activity: com.mypay/.MainActivity
TotalTime: 595
WaitTime: 600
Complete


So these commends open the app, but on the Home screen, not on the OBPaymentResults which is what i expect.
Finally, here is the output of adb shell pm get-app-links
com.mypay:
    ID: efc-f825-4d37-91be-af1750
    Signatures: [FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C]
    Domain verification state:
      whimsysketchbook.com: 1024


Add linking to NavigationContainer
